# Modify XAML string dynamically

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to add/remove some part of XAML dynamically i.e. from code behind file in C#.how to  Add any specific XAML string on specified location (means under some tag) from .cs file. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

XAML is xml you can use XmlReader and XmlWriter or any other of the XML serialization mechanismn of .NET to write/read XML (XMlDocument is probably the best approach here to modify existing xml). ALso there are the XamlReader and XamlWriter class that allow ou to (de)serialize any object graph from/to XAML automatically. If you can use .NET 4.0, you have even more fine grained possibilities to athor XAML because it has a new XAML stack. Use [this](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/05/19/xaml2009-and-system-xaml-dll-preview-in-net-fx-4-beta1.aspx) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

What is it that modifying the XAML will do for you?

If you just want to change the appearance of your WPF application (perhaps by adding some more content at certain locations), it will most likely be easier to do this by referencing the objects in question.  So, if you need to add some text to a button, name the button with `x:Name="myButton"` and in code set: `myButton.Content = "Click Me"`

XAML is really a technology for constructing object hierarchies.  Pretty much every element in the XAML corresponds to a .NET CLR class.  When loaded, these classes are instantiated nd populated according to the attributes used in the XAML.  Once loaded, the XAML has finished it's job and is essentially unloaded/unavailable.

You might need to do something beyond this, but from your brief question it doesn't seem like it.  I would just work on the object model and leave the XAML be.